# how i can print the 3rd word fom the end to extract number in awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

How i can print the 3rd word from the end to print the numbers:

```
alberto 123 brazil argantino
drakola almond 4567 beta alpha
dream delta 5671 earth england
```

i test this code:

```
awk '{print ($0+0)}'
```

but not work with me.

the result:

```
123
4567
5671
```

and i test this code:

```
tmp=$0
num= gsub(/[^0-9]/, " ",tmp)
print substr($0, RSTART,RLENGTH), num, header   > result[value]
```

but give me wrong numbers.

Comment: Printing the second last column is `print $(NF-2)` but in your provided awk code  `num` gives back the number of replacements, and as you are not using the match function  in the example code, this part `substr($0, RSTART,RLENGTH)` will become `substr($0, 0,0)` which will print an empty string. Can you update the question to make it a bit more clear what you want to print?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NF built-in variable (the number of fields) minus 2, e.g.

```
cat test.txt
alberto 123 brazil argantino
drakola almond 4567 beta alpha
dream delta 5671 earth england

awk '{print $(NF-2)}' test.txt
123
4567
5671
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: thank you mr.pete, not work, my code : print substr($0, RSTART,RLENGTH), $(NF-2), header   < result[value]

Comment: @pete_999999999 : ur solution may error out if input rows happen to have fewer than 3 fields

Answer (score 2):

> `num= gsub(/[^0-9]/, " ",tmp)`
>
> give(...)wrong numbers

[`gsub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) does affect 3rd argument and return number of substitutions made, therefore `num` is number of non-digit characters, I would ameloriate your code following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
alberto 123 brazil argantino
drakola almond 4567 beta alpha
dream delta 5671 earth england
```

then

```
awk '{tmp=$0;gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",tmp);print tmp}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
123
4567
5671
```

Changes: replacement is empty string rather than space in order to get just digits, not digits with ton of leading and trailing spaces, `tmp` is `print`ed which does hold altered string, no `num` is created as you do not have use for quantity of non-digits characters in line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: thank you, my code her : print substr($0, RSTART,RLENGTH), num, header   > result[value] , not word.

Comment: @Daweo: ur solution may inadvertently concat numbers that exist in fields other than `$(NF-2)`

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you're ***only*** extracting numbers from 3rd-last column, you can try this :

> ```
> echo "${test_1}\n\nalpha567beta delta omicron gamma epsilon mu phi sigma"
> ```

```
alberto 123 brazil argantino
drakola almond 4567 beta alpha
dream delta 5671 earth england

alpha567beta delta omicron gamma epsilon mu phi sigma
```

> ```
> echo "${test_1}\n\nalpha567beta delta omicron gamma epsilon mu phi sigma" | 
>
> mawk '(_+=_?!_:++_)<NF && ($!NF=$(NF-_))~"^[0-9]+$"'
> ```

```
123
4567
5671
```

The `567` sandwiched within `$1` of last row is now properly skipped

- note : this makes assumption only unformatted unsigned integers without a decimal point or scientific notation exist in `$(NF-2)`. if anything else also exists there, no print out would be generated for that row.

Comment: Can you can please add some explanation to your answer what `(_+=_?!_:++_)<NF` does and `($!NF=$(NF-_))` for future readers?

Comment: @Thefourthbird : first part initializes `_` to value of 2 to ensure we don't reference a negative field number, second half sets 3rd last field as the new `$0`, then regex check to ensure only numbers exists there